# Do forests with Vietnamese districts on them count as "unimproved features"?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6, governor Reyna can give +2 gold for each unimporved feature in a city. Do forests with Vietnamese districts on them count?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unimproved means not touched.

Anything you build on a tile (with a builder) is called an *improvement*, regardless of whether it partially preserves some of the scenery or not.

Comment: But districts aren't built with builders?

Comment: @tog22 Districts aren't called improvements, hence why I phrased it that way.